# Отличие между const string &s и string &s

Tags: c++

столкнулся с одной проблемой, и не могу понять, почему так происходит.

Допустим, есть некая функция

```
vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {}
```

Если её вызвать просто как `vector<string>s = split("pam.pam", '.');`, то всё будет хорошо и код отработает. Однако, если убрать в аргументах ключевое слово `const`, то программа не будет компилироваться. Почему так?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В ответ на ваше `"pam.pam"` компилятор создает временный объект типа `std::string`. Lvalue-ссылки можно привязывать ко временным объектам только если эти ссылки являются `const`. Так было всегда.

```
const std::string &s1 = "pam.pam"; // <- Все в порядке
std::string &s2 = "pam.pam";       // <- А так нельзя
```

---

Вопрос тут в том, зачем вам вдруг понадобилось убирать этот `const`. Если вы хотите модифицировать `s` внутри вашей функции и при этом считаете, что "само собой разумеется", что передаваемое пользователем значение аргумента будет модифицировано/повреждено/разрушено, то можно предоставить перегрузки

```
vector<std::string> split(std::string &s, char delim) 
{
  ...
}

vector<std::string> split(std::string &&s, char delim) 
{
  return split(s, delim);
}
```

Если же вы хотите, чтобы значение аргумента не разрушалось и при этом не делалось затрат на копирование, когда оно не нужно, то проще всего сделать

```
vector<std::string> split(std::string s, char delim) 
{
  ...
}
```

Оба варианта позволят вам делать

```
split("pam.pam", '.');
```

Comment: почему в коде `vector<std::string> split(std::string s, char delim)` Вы говорите про отсутствие затрат на копирование, если оба аргумента передаются по значению?

Comment: @Bogdan: Я говорю об отсутствии *лишних* затрат на копирование. Если пользователь хочет сохранить аргумент неповрежденным, то без копирования никак не обойтись и копирование будет. Если же пользователю все равно, он может передавать аргумент через `std::move` и вместо копирования будет выполнено перемещение. То же самое произойдет само по себе с временными объектами. То есть копирования не будет - будет перемещение.